# Is it possible in SQL Server to apply s lock and x lock on the same row in the same transaction?

Tags: sql-server

In Repeatable Read isolation shared locks and exclusive locks are applied until the end of the transaction. Now consider below mentioned query which has clustered index on id column and nonclustered index on name and col1

```
Set transaction isolation level repeatable read
begin transaction
update tableA
set name = 'abc'
where id = 1

select name, col
from tableA
where id = 1

commit transaction
```

How does SQL Server handle locks in this scenario? Will put two locks - X lock and S Lock on the row with ID = 1 or X lock will be converted to S lock.

I am confused here. Can someone put more light on this locking behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect the locks taken/hold by enabling the following traceflags, or by looking in to the sys.dm_tran_locks view.

**Do not run these traceflags in production environments.**

The traceflags will output the locks acquired/released in the messages.

In this test, it seems it is holding the X-lock and also acquiring an S-lock on the same RID. The output from sys.dm_tran_locks suggest that only the X lock is actually held.

Your results may vary.

```
DBCC TRACEON(1200,-1,3604);
SET transaction isolation level repeatable read
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE dbo.Customer SET name = 'peter';
SELECT * FROM dbo.Customer WHERE id = 1

DBCC TRACEOFF(1200,-1,3604);
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE request_session_id = @@SPID

COMMIT
```

Output from the traceflag:

> Process 56 acquiring S lock on DATABASE: 13 [PLANGUIDE] (class bit0
>   ref1) result: OK
>
> Process 56 releasing lock on DATABASE: 13 [PLANGUIDE]
>
> DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your
>   system administrator.
>
> Process 56 acquiring IX lock on OBJECT:
>   13:1920061926:0  (class bit2000000 ref1) result: OK
>
> Process 56 acquiring IU lock on PAGE: 13:1:2150  (class bit2000000
>   ref0) result: OK
>
> Process 56 acquiring U lock on RID: 13:1:2150:0 (class bit2000000
>   ref0) result: OK
>
> Process 56 acquiring IX lock on PAGE: 13:1:2150  (class bit2000000
>   ref0) result: OK
>
> Process 56 acquiring X lock on RID: 13:1:2150:0 (class bit2000000
>   ref0) result: OK
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> Process 56 acquiring IS lock on PAGE: 13:1:2150 
>   (class bit2000000 ref0) result: OK
>
> Process 56 acquiring S lock on RID: 13:1:2150:0 (class bit2000000
>   ref0) result: OK
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> Process 56 releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 finished releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 finished releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 finished releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 finished releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 finished releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 finished releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> Process 56 finished releasing all locks @00000002E54015A8
>
> (4 row(s) affected) DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error
>   messages, contact your system administrator.

Comment: great Explanation. I appreciate your time and effort

Answer (score 2):

Well, since it's inside the **same transaction**, SQL Server of course *knows* what you have changed / updated and can return that to your `SELECT`.

The `X` exclusive lock only prevents **OTHER** transactions from reading that data while it's being updated. The `X` lock will stay in place until the `COMMIT` has been executed.

If you pause your execution after the `UPDATE`, and then switch to another SSMS window and execute the `SELECT` there, it will be **blocked** from reading that row being updated